# C# How to cast a strong datatype?

Tags: c#

I hope some of you guys can help me with this problem....

I have a class library containing amongst other things 1 complex class. this class library is used in 2 other projects in the solution. 1 = Console Application , 2 = Web Service Application (Web Site Application).

In the console application I have created an asmx web service reference, which passes my complex class as the 1 parameter in a method call.

The class is of type : ScheduleSummaryTransport

The function that does the work in the console app is expecting the object bound from the class library DLL, and not from the web service reference. However the web service call is expecting the parameter of type... from the web service reference.

So how can I cast

ClassLibrary.ScheduleSummaryTransport -> WebService.ScheduleSummaryTransport ?

I've tried:

```
wsReporting.SendReportSummary( (Reporting.ScheduleSummaryTransport) scheduleSummary);
```

But in visual studio its detected a design time error : Cannot cast expression.....

Please assist, and thanks

**Update**

For completeness more code:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Sends the schedule report via email.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="scheduleSummary">
        /// The schedule summary.
        /// </param>
        private static void SendScheduleReport(ScheduleSummaryTransport scheduleSummary)
        {
            if (!Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSummary"]))
            {
                return;
            }

            Trace.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            Trace.WriteLine("Sending summary by email... please wait ");

            Reporting.Reporting wsReporting = new Reporting.Reporting { Timeout = -1 };
            wsReporting.SendReportSummary( (Reporting.ScheduleSummaryTransport) scheduleSummary);
            Trace.WriteLine("Done...");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebService Proxy generator (wsdl.exe) generates a class for you to hold all information about objects transmitted via the webservice.
This new class conflicts with the class referenced in the client.

You need to get rid of the auto-generated classes. To do this, show all files in your solution explorer (Icon at the top). There will be a class Reference.cs as a child of your Webservice Reference, where you can find the autogenerated code. Add a `using ClassLibrary` there and delete all code concerning the duplicate classes.

Worked for me. =)

Answer (score 3):

If they're unrelated types, you *can't* cast between them. It's like trying to cast from `String` to `MemoryStream` - what would you expect to happen? The compiler knows that would never work, so it stops you from trying it.

The problem here is having multiple types in the first place. Avoid that if you can *possibly* do so. If you can't, you'll need to write some sort of conversion method two convert between the two types.

Comment: They're exactly the same object. C# Console gets the reference from the ClassLibrary DLL, but the WS method is expecting the same object , but reference routed through the WS Proxy... but in the class library - only 1 object exists... (sorry hard to explain Jon)...

Comment: @JL - You try editing the web service definition .cs so it's expecting this type?  Sounds more of a web service reference import problem than anything.

Comment: @JL: You only think they're the same.  But in .NET, type identity includes the assembly where the type is declared, so even putting the same exact source file into two projects creates two different and incompatible types.

Comment: @Ben - From what I understand, it's even in the same assembly being used in both projects...but the web reference when generating code doesn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unclear why you have two different versions of the same class but if you can't get to where you're referencing and using the version in the class library in both places, you might want to check out [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to handle mapping from one version to the other.